# Is it possible to write a query with multiple dynamic pivots?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-design

I have tables like

```
   Partners
===============
id |   name 
---------------
 1 | "John" 
 2 | "Jacob"


   Regions
====================
id | name
--------------------
 1 | "Antarctica"
 2 | "Coruscant"
 3 | "Iraq"

      Destinations 
============================
id | partner_id | region_id 
----------------------------
1  |     1      |    1
2  |     1      |    2
3  |     2      |    2

    Surveys
================
id | title
----------------
 1 | "Part 1"
 2 | "Bonus" 


      Versions 
======================
id |    title   
----------------------
 1 | "First Version"
 2 | "Version #2" 


              Permissions
==========================================
id | partner_id | survey_id | version_id
------------------------------------------
1  |     1      |     1     |     1
2  |     1      |     1     |     2
3  |     2      |     1     |     1


             Sections
=======================================
id | survey_id |   title 
---------------------------------------
 1 |    1      | "Some Section"
 2 |    1      | "Some Other Section"
 3 |    2      | "Yet Another Section"


        Subsections
=================================
id |    title    | section_id 
--------------------------------
 1 | "Subsec"    |     1
 2 | "Subsecc"   |     1
 3 |   "Ss"      |     2 
 4 |  "kasjhja"  |     3
 5 | "aslkdjas"  |     3


                         Questions
===================================================================
id | subsection_id |             qtext            |   version_id
-------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 |      1        | "What is 1+1?"               |       1
 2 |      1        | "What is 2+2?"               |       1
 3 |      1        | "What is one plus one?"      |       2
 4 |      1        | "What is two plus two?"      |       2
 5 |      2        | "How are you doing?"         |       1
 6 |      2        | "What's up?"                 |       2 
 7 |      3        | "What would you rate her?"   |       1
 8 |      3        | "What would you rate her?"   |       2
 9 |      4        | "Number of bits in a byte?"  |       1
10 |      5        | "What year is it?"           |       1
11 |      5        | "The year is ...."?          |       2

              Answers
========================================
id | question_id | partner_id |   val 
---------------------------------------- 
 1 |      1      |     1      |  2 
 2 |      1      |     2      |  2
 3 |      2      |     1      |  4 
 4 |      2      |     2      |  4
 5 |      3      |     1      |  2
 6 |      4      |     1      |  69
 7 |      5      |     1      |  55
 8 |      6      |     1      |  10
 9 |      7      |     1      |  9
10 |      8      |     1      |  10
11 |      9      |     1      |  8
12 |     10      |     1      |  2016
13 |     11      |     1      |  2016


            MarkedAsFinished
===========================================
 id | partner_id | survey_id | version_id 
-------------------------------------------
  1 |    1       |    1      |     1
  2 |    1       |    2      |     1
  3 |    1       |    1      |     2
  4 |    2       |    1      |     1
```

where the PK/FK relationships are self-explanatory from my naming conventions. If possible, I'd like a query

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AnswerDump 
   @versid INT
AS
   ...
```

that would, for example, return the following table if executed with `versid` (corresponding to `Versions.id`) equal to `1`.

```
   name    | Destined for Antarctica? | Destined for Coruscant? | Destined for Iraq? | Finished with Part 1? | Finished with Bonus? | Permission to contact about Part 1? | Permission to contact about Bonus? | What is 1+1? | What is 2+2? | How are you doing? | What would you rate her? | Number of bits in a byte? | What year is it?
=============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 "John"    |          Yes             |           Yes           |        No          |          Yes          |         Yes          |                Yes                  |                   No               |       2      |      4       |        55          |             9            |             8             |       2016
 "Jacob"   |          No              |           Yes           |        No          |          Yes          |         No           |                Yes                  |                   No               |       2      |      4       |        0           |             0            |             0             |        0
```

So what it basically does is use `Partners` as rows and all other associated information as columns. You can see that it fills in answers of zero for questions that have not yet been filled out.

Sorry if this seems like a "Write my code for me" question, but I did put a lot of effort into writing it ...

Comment: Great that you post tables with sample data, but http://sqlfiddle.com will be much better. Converting text to script takes time.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: This does not seem like a write my code for me question -- BECAUSE YOU DON'T HAVE A QUESTION.  However, if your question is What code should I write, then it is a write the code for me.  So... what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible, but no within a SQL view, you need to develop them in a SQL function or SP.

An Example of a SQL pivot would be the following:

Normal SQL:

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2 ;
GO
SELECT DaysToManufacture, AVG(StandardCost) AS AverageCost 
FROM Production.Product
GROUP BY DaysToManufacture;
```

Pivot SQL:

```
-- Pivot table with one row and five columns
SELECT 'AverageCost' AS Cost_Sorted_By_Production_Days, 
[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]
FROM
(SELECT DaysToManufacture, StandardCost 
    FROM Production.Product) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
AVG(StandardCost)
FOR DaysToManufacture IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4])
) AS PivotTable;
```